# How do you assert the type of a component as prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass a component as prop.

The component:

```
export type ItemProps= {
  //...
};

export const Item = ({ /* ... */ }: ItemProps) => {
  return (
    //...
  );
};
```

Where I'm attempting to pass it:

```
type ParentProps= {
  //...
  item: ReactElement<ItemProps>;
};

export const Parent = ({ /* ... */, item }: ParentProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {item}
    </>
  );
};
```

---

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
export const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Parent item={ <Item /> } />
  );
};
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass the `Item` component as a prop in the `Parent` component. As of now, this *works*, but it seems that using ReactElement loosens the type to `ReactElement<ItemProps, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>`, or more generally:

`ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>`.

The issue: if I were to replace  with any other component, there wouldn't be any explicit warning or error about the component being different. I am trying to instead narrow it such that *only* the `<Item />` component can be passed for the `item={}` prop of `<Parent />`.

In essence, what are some ways that can explicitly define a specific React component as a prop for a parent React component?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Component returns `JSX.Element`, And the `JSX.Element` was extended from `ReactElement`.

```js
interface Element extends React.ReactElement<any, any> { }
```

And I think if you want to assert the component that receives from the parent Component, you can receive the complete component like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vq5wdb?file=App.tsx)